# Android SharedPreferences confusion

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am a beginner in android and I have a confusion regarding Shared Preferences implementation. My goal is to use a string where a user defines some text which will be used in MainFragment. Given the fact that user may change that string when application is running I need a listener as well. So according to one book so far I have a SettingsActivity and a SettingsFragment.

SettingsActivity so far:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String stringIWantToSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment(), "settings_fragment").commit();
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    stringIWantToSave = prefs.getString("stringIWantToSave", "myString");

}

}
```

SettingsFragment so far:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private String stringIWantToSave;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sharedPreferences.getString("stringIWantToSave", "myString");
    sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

}
}
```

My questions are:

• In which method and how should I save the changed value from the user?

• How can I implement the listener so that it will inform the MainFragment that the string has changed?

Comment: Those are classes for Settings activity and fragment, you probably won't need them. I don't know what you are trying to do, but if you know when the user can change this string, you can just check after it if it has change. SharedPreferences can be used in all Activity and Fragment classes.

Comment: @fapps I am trying to provide the user with the ability to change let's say his name. I decided to put a menu and inside the menu a tab called settings where an EditTextPreference will allow the user to write down his name. That's why I have created those classes.

Comment: So if you are using an EditTextPreference in the xml layout, just set the key value with `key="stringIWantToSave"` and that will do everything you need. No extra code.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** To achieve the `SettingsActivity` with `EditTextPreference`, first you have to create a `PreferenceScreen` that contains `EditTextPreference`.

**preferences.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_key_name"
        android:title="Name"
        android:summary="Enter your name here!"
        android:dialogTitle="Enter name:">

    </EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**2.** Create a `Fragment` extending `PreferenceFragment`. Do preference `initialization` and add `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to `update` the UI when `user` input their `name`.

**SettingsFragment.java:**

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    // Preference Keys
    public static final String KEY_PREF_NAME = "pref_key_name";

    // Shared preference
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Name preference
    EditTextPreference mPreferenceName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        // Shared preference
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        // Name preference
        mPreferenceName = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY_PREF_NAME);

        // Initialize
        initPreferences();
    }

    public void initPreferences()
    {
        // Name
        String oldName = mSharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PREF_NAME, "Enter your name here!");
        // Update view
        mPreferenceName.setSummary(oldName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPref, String key) {

        if(key.equals(KEY_PREF_NAME))
        {
            // Name
            String currentName = sharedPref.getString(key, "DEFAULT_VALUE");
            // Update view
            mPreferenceName.setSummary(currentName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

**3.** Finally, Create `SettingsActivity` and show `SettingsFragment` on its `FrameLayout`.

**SettingsActivity.java:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        // Settings Fragment
        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, settingsFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

**HOW TO USE:**

To use updated `name` from `preference`, get the `name` value from `preference` inside your `activity` or `fragments` `onResume()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        // Name
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString(SettingsFragment.KEY_PREF_NAME, "DEFAULT_VALUE");

        // Do something with name
        ................
        ........................
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~